# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 662250 into shape (883,22,1000,1)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

how can I shape this to 4D in python-3.x

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-3ebb07a7b8c5> in <module>
----> 1 x_train = x_train.reshape((n_samples_train, 22, 1000, 1))
  2 x_test = x_test.reshape((n_samples_test, 22, 1000, 1))
  3 
  4 print(x_train.shape)
  5 print(x_test.shape)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 662250 into shape (883,22,1000,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`883x22x1000x1 = 18.326.000`, which of course is different from `662.250`. Ensure you reshape in a correct format.